# Why is Angular saying my component is not standalone when it is?

Tags: angular

I have the following component which was declared standalone:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-header',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

I import this component in app.component.ts as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/components/footer/footer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  imports: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'client';
}
```

I get the following error message during transpilation:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:9:12 - error NG2010: 'imports' is only valid on a 
component that is standalone.

9   imports: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:11:14
    11 export class AppComponent {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Did you forget to add 'standalone: true' to this @Component?
```

Comment: The error says that your app component is not stand alone!

Comment: Because it's telling you about the other one, that's not...

Comment: I did not create AppComponent, Angular did during the creation of the application. AppComponent is used in AppModule so it cannot be standalone.

Comment: To clarify the other vague commenters, the error is saying that you can't use `imports` in a component that is not `standalone`. Assuming that your `AppComponent` is declared in your `AppModule`, both `HeaderComponent` and `FooterComponent` should be imported into the `AppModule`, not `AppComponent`,

Comment: @koque Standalone components can be used to bootstrap an angular application, meaning that `AppComponent` can be marked as standalone.
https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#bootstrapping-an-application-using-a-standalone-component

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing my standalone component in AppComponent as I did in my original question:

```
imports: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
```

import and export the standalone components in AppModule like so:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Their selectors can then be used in app.component.html like so:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

for a child standalone component to work in a parent component you need to first check whether the parent component is standalone or not

if parent component is standalone -> your imports are the way to go ;
else -> you got to import it in declarations inside the module where the parent component is also added

Edited:
Also you can make your whole project standalone with BootStrap Application in main.ts, u can pass your App component and module imports there as well
then you wont be seeing any module.ts in your project

Answer (score 0):

Your app component is not **standalone**.

Try to make it **standalone: true** -- ***Not preferred to do manually.***

---

**(Follow this..........)**

Use command line interface for perfect migration.

run below command in your root project.

**ng generate @angular/core:standalone**

For mor visit

https://next.angular.io/guide/standalone-migration